# What are the six openings on the bottom of the MacBook Pro for?

Tags: hardware, macbook-pro

I have a 2013 Retina MacBook Pro. I have noticed there are six slits, three on each side, on the base of the laptop.

[image: The slits are marked here.]

What are these for, and if I were to use them as a place to clip something, would it affect my computer?

Comment: I assume it's for cooling, so clipping would probably be fine as long as you're not running CPU intensive stuff, and don't block them completely.  Out of curiosity, what kind of clips?

Comment: The clips are just sort of hooks that come from below the laptop (they're connected to something else) and they'd just come straight up alongside the laptop then curve into the openings. Sorry if I can't explain them very well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

Plug your computer in and set it on a table
Play a long video from youtube
after about 10 minutes but your palm next to those holes on either side of the macbook

feel warm air?
Then they are cooling vents.

I would be loathe to block these with ANYTHING.

But them I am a bit paranoid about keeping my electronics cooled properly...

Comment: As long as you're not going above like 80 degrees, it really doesn't matter. Operating temperatures of these components are really wide ranges

Answer (score 5):

They're vents for air:

[image]

…but they're *not just for air*. They are also used as part of the structural system of the machine.

> The vents are also part of the structural system creating strong beams that actually increase the rigidity of the overall product.

[image]

This Apple video explains it very well:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Neff9scaCCI&t=3m20s

Comment: Video link is dead.